# How to reindex columns in two pandas dataframes so that they both have the same columns?

Tags: python, pandas, reindex

I have two dataframes

```
df1
>>>
   a  b
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6

df2
>>>
   a  c
0  9  8
1  0  1
2  0  0
```

What I would like to  do is create the non-overlapping columns in each dataframe and fill them with zero's. So, because `df1` does not contain column `c` from `df2`, and `df2` does not contain column `b` from `df1`, the end result would be

```
df1
>>>
   a  b  c
0  1  4  0
1  2  5  0
2  3  6  0

df2
>>>
   a  c  b
0  9  8  0
1  0  1  0
2  0  0  0
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

I have tried using `reindex` and `reindex_like`, but the former only seems to reindex rows rather than columns and I don't know what argument to use to reindex the columns

```
df1.reindex(df2.columns, fill_value=0.)
>>>
     a    b
a  0.0  0.0
c  0.0  0.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.align`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.align.html):

```
df1, df2 = df1.align(df2, fill_value=0)
print (df1)
print (df2)
   a  b  c
0  1  4  0
1  2  5  0
2  3  6  0
   a  b  c
0  9  0  8
1  0  0  1
2  0  0  0
```

Your solution with [`Index.union`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.union.html) and [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with `axis=1` for columns:

```
c = df1.columns.union(df2.columns)
df1, df2 = df1.reindex(c, fill_value=0, axis=1), df2.reindex(c, fill_value=0, axis=1)
print (df1)
print (df2)
   a  b  c
0  1  4  0
1  2  5  0
2  3  6  0
   a  b  c
0  9  0  8
1  0  0  1
2  0  0  0
```